# App.Config ASMX issue

Tags: c#, asmx

I have an app.Config that was created on the dev machine running Windows 7.

It created the following asmx related configuration section:

```
  <applicationSettings>
    <ISDS_Scheduler.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="Scheduler_WSDownloads_Downloads" serializeAs="String">
        <value>[address]/Downloads.asmx</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="Scheduler_WSTasks_WSTasks" serializeAs="String">
        <value>[address]/WSTasks.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </ISDS_Scheduler.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

Its been a while since I used ASMX, but when I deploy to Windows 2003 Server, I get the error unrecognised configuration section applicationSettings.

Any one know how I can manually fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to fix:

Needed to include the config section... located at the top of the app.config file...

```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="Scheduler.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```